# Paypal API with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, curl, paypal, oauth-2.0

I'm making a PayPal API call in the context of an e-Commerce solution I'm developing in Angular-JS. I was able to get an auth_token back from PayPal using the following code.
my code :

```
var basicAuthString = btoa('AUAlrIhHNoiQlmaW.............:EJk......');
         $http({

         url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             'Authorization': 'Basic ' + basicAuthString,
         }, 
                 data: { 'grant_type': 'client_credentials' }
         }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                     console.log(data)
         }).error(function (error) {
             console.log("erreur "+error);
         });
```

When sending the data , I receiving an error

```
error:{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"Grant Type is NULL"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should send the grant type like this:

```
 data: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```